# Android Launch app from the http URL Schema does not work

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent

Hi I am getting a bit desperate since I am not able to make work the http schema in order to invoke an app from the browser/external link.

I would like to start my app from an external link. In my app, I declared 2 different activities to test. One has attached a http scheme and the other has a custom scheme.

Activity1:

```
   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.myapp.example.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />

            </intent-filter>
```

Activity2:

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="myapp.example.com"
                    android:scheme="custom" />
            </intent-filter>
```

On a static website I create the following js code:

BUTTON 1 -> window.location.replace("custom://myapp.example.com");

BUTTON 2 -> window.location.replace("http://myapp.example.com");

The results are the following. From Firefox, by accessing the website I am able to call the app from the Custom shema (BUTTON1) but from the http one, it results in a invalid website.

I would like to make the http sheme works because I need to call the website from a webview inside an app, and then return to the same app, but the custom scheme does not work.

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated since I tried many solutions and none of them work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you a mistake in Activity 1.

the host should exclude www.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="myapp.example.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />

            </intent-filter>
```